# Pass the "method()" portion of Object.method() as a parameter

Tags: python, string, function, parameters

First, let me say that this is a hackerrank question which, though I could do it hackily, is allowing me to indulge my deeper python curiosities.

I would welcome comments on my general approach, but my specific question relates to the title of this post.

Question:

> *Task*
>
> You are given a string S.  Your task is to find if string S contains,
>   alphanumeric characters, alphabetical characters, digits, lowercase
>   and uppercase characters.
>
> *Input Format*
>
> Single line containing, string S.
>
> *Constraints*
>
> 0
>
> *Output Format*
>
> In First line, print True if S has any alphanumeric character, otherwise print False.
>
> In Second line, print True if S has any alphabetical character, otherwise print False.
>
> In Third line, print True if S has any digits, otherwise print False.
>
> In Fourth line, print True if S has any lowercase character, otherwise print False.
>
> In Fifth line, print True if S has any uppercase character, otherwise print False.

Attempted Code:

```
S = input()

def testing(S, fun):
    for x in S:
        if x.fun:
            print(x.fun)
            break
    else:
        print(False)

testing(S, .isalnum())
testing(S, .isalpha())
testing(S, .isdigit())
testing(S, .islower())
testing(S, .isupper())
```

I'm not sure how to get my string methods into my `testing` function in a way that lets me run them against *each* letter of the string(s).

I could obviously pass a kwarg and do a select-case, but that's not what I'm looking for. I'm sure there's a way to do this with lambdas (perhaps instead of passing `.method()` I would pass `lambda x: x.method()`), but (1) I'm not too sure about lambdas, and (2) I have this theory that I'd really like to write code that a beginner can always read, and lambdas aren't beginner.

Comment: *Aside*: Here is an alternative: `print (any(ch.isupper() for ch in S))`

Answer (score 3):

You can assign an instance method to a variable as if it were a normal function, by using the class name that declares the method. For instance:

```
fun = str.isalnum
print (fun('123'))
```

So your code would end up looking something like this:

```
def testing(S, fun):
    for x in S:
        if fun(x):
            print(fun(x))
            break
    else:
        print(False)

testing(S, str.isalnum)
```

or more succinctly:

```
def testing(S, fun):
    print(any(fun(x) for x in S))
```

Comment: Thanks! That's cool that `fun(x) for x in S` returns an iterable. How did you learn that? I've been looking around for an advanced python course - any recommendations?

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner It is called a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). [Google's python class](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/?hl=en) is pretty good, but I don't remember which topics it covers.

Comment: Thanks! I have been looking at this one: https://www.udemy.com/python-the-next-level/. $69 worth it you think, or is there a book you'd recommend for the $?

Comment: I haven't read any python books, so I can't recommend any. Good luck.